# How to select the indexPath of the UITableView after a pop?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a RootViewController that is a UIViewController with a UITableView.  This RootViewController pushes a ChildViewController based on the row selected.  When I pop the ChildViewController and go back to the RootViewController, I want to be able to know the indexPath that was selected.  Once I have the indexPath, I want to call the selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: method to scroll that selected indexPath to the top.

I know how to grab the selected indexPath within the tableview (indexPathForSelectedRow) but I don't know how to hold onto that value when I push the ChildViewController and then pop back to the RootViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field to your table view controller .h file:,

```
    NSIndexPath* selectedIndexPath;

    //...
}

//...

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath* selectedIndexPath;

//...

@end
```

and then add

```
@synthesize selectedIndexPath;
```

in your .m file. After that, store the value using

```
    self.selectedIndexPath = myIndexPath;
```

and then use it as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and accurate answer.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

use static variable it will hold Your Cellselected Indexpath.row value..

for your class only declare it in .h file in static method or class otherwise before @implemented

static int tableIndex = nil;

didselect row at path >>>table view Delegate method

tableindex = indexpath.row;

> > view will appear ..

if(tableIndex !=nil){
     //do stuff
}

Thanks